# jQuery dialog-form: Tracking whether 'OK' or 'Cancel' was clicked

Tags: jquery

In the below jQuery UI dialog-form, how can I track inside the 'close' callback function that whether 'OK' or 'Cancel' was clicked?

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", 
    [ 
        { 
            text: "OK", 
            click: function() { 
                // sone action...
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel", 
            click: function() { 
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ] 
);

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // Track here whether 'OK' or 'Cancel' was clicked...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a built-in way to do it, you could do something like this:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", 
    [ 
        { 
            text: "OK", 
            click: function() { 
                // sone action...
                $("#dialog-form").data({ lastClick: 'ok' });
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel", 
            click: function() { 
                $("#dialog-form").data({ lastClick: 'close' });
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ] 
);

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // Track here whether 'OK' or 'Cancel' was clicked...
        var lastClick = $("#dialog-form").data('lastClick');
        if(lastClick)
            console.log(lastClick);
    }
});
```

Comment: @x-raj Not the prettiest solution but I guess it'll do